# C Sorting of String arrays with exec() and fork ();

Tags: c, sorting, fork, exec

Could someone please explain to me how `for()` and `exec()` works for calling system calls like `sort`? I've been reading around, but still quite confused. My data is stored in a .txt file looks like:

```
00-11-D9-20-AA-4E       951
CC-3A-61-DF-4B-61       259
84-1B-5E-A8-BF-7F       82
74-E2-F5-17-96-89       829
84-1B-5E-A8-BF-7C       56
```

The space in the center is tab delimited. I'm trying to sort out the values based on the second field decreasing with `exec()` and `sort()`. But no idea how to. I've called `fork()` to complete the sorting in a separate process. Then, returning to the parent to print out the results to the console.

```
int pid;
    FILE *data;
    char line[LINESIZE];
    data = fopen("results.txt", "r");
    switch(pid = fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("fork()");
            exit(1);
            break;

        case 0:
            break;

        default:
            sleep(3);
            while(fgets(line, sizeof line, data) != NULL){
                printf("%s", line);
            }
            printf("arrived at parent");
            break;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: `sort` is not a **system call**. `sort` is an utility program. Also, why would you want to use `sort` and not *C* for that task? In any case, `fork`+`exec` for this is like "I want to build a house, I've got a saw and hammer, where do I begin"; perhaps you'd want to look into `popen` instead.

Comment: How would you sort the data using the `sort` command from the command line?  You'll need to make the child process do the same.  Then you 'just' have to sort out the plumbing — how is the data getting to the `sort` command, and how is your program retrieving the output from the sort command.  There are lots of ways to do it.  Some of them involve pipes.  Others involve files.  You'll probably need `wait()` or `waitpid()` too.

Comment: This is the part that I'm a bit confused about. How exactly would you use exec to call the usr/bin/sort command? I've looked through man and several other posts, but I still don't understand the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finished it,you can have a try.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define LINESIZE 1024
int main()
{
    int pid;
    FILE *data;
    int fd;
    char line[LINESIZE];
    data = fopen("results.txt","r");
    switch(pid=fork())
    {
        case -1:
            perror("fork()");
            exit(1);
            break;
        case 0:
            fd = open("results.txt",O_WRONLY);
            dup2(fd,1); //output redirection from stdout to results.txt
            execl("/usr/bin/sort",".","a.txt\0",NULL);
            break;
        default:
            sleep(3);
            while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),data) != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s",line);
            }
            printf("arrived at parent");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Also, using `waitpid()` would be a better solution that `sleep(3)`